# Как сделать названия папок и файлов цветным в выводе команды ls?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wsl2, ls

столкнулась с проблемой: в какой-то момент пропало цветное выделение папок/файлов/архивов при выполнении команды ls в терминале. Как можно это исправить?
Советы из интернета не помогли, буду благодарна опытным пользователям linux за рекомендации

Использую wsl2. Версия Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$ env -i COLORTERM=truecolor ls --color=always` - цвет есть.

Comment: получилось, спасибо большое!

Comment: надеюсь, вы догадались, что программу env (с передачей ей опции `-i`) я здесь использовал исключительно для демонстрации работоспособности программы ls в чистом окружении?

Comment: да, проблема в итоге оказалась в поломанном .bashrc файле, все починила и все работает